# Crash: NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid rowCache row is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

I'm having an issue with CoreData concurrency on iOS 8.1.

I'm getting the following stack trace for the crash:

`NSInternalInconsistencyException - Invalid rowCache row is nil`

```
0     CoreFoundation                        0x0000000183b6659c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x00000001942640e4 objc_exception_throw + 56
2     CoreData                              0x000000018385b8b8 -[NSSQLCore _newRowCacheRowForToManyUpdatesForRelationship:rowCacheOriginal:originalSnapshot:value:added:deleted:sourceRowPK:properties:sourceObject:newIndexes:reorderedIndexes:] + 6668
3     CoreData                              0x00000001838fbea0 -[NSSQLCore recordToManyChangesForObject:inRow:usingTimestamp:inserted:] + 2604
4     CoreData                              0x0000000183857638 -[NSSQLCore prepareForSave:] + 1052
5     CoreData                              0x00000001838569b4 -[NSSQLCore saveChanges:] + 520
6     CoreData                              0x000000018381f078 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 716
7     CoreData                              0x00000001838e6254 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 4048
8     CoreData                              0x00000001838ed654 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 176
9     libdispatch.dylib                     0x00000001948a936c _dispatch_client_callout + 12
10   libdispatch.dylib                      0x00000001948b26e8 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 72
11   CoreData                               0x00000001838e0cb4 _perform + 176
12   CoreData                               0x000000018381ec34 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 296
13   CoreData                               0x0000000183845400 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 1280
```

This crash happens in several places (about 20), but is most prominent in my data import function which imports 1000s of records and saves every 100.

A few notes about my CoreData setup:

- I'm using the ["Stack #3" from this blog post](http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/)
- All of my managed object updating/saving code is done on a `performBlock:`
- The crashes are all on the background context

The code where all of these saves are occurring has the following basic pattern:

```
[backgroundContext performBlock:^{
    ...
    NSArray *result = [backgroundContext fetch...];
    ...

    if ([backgroundContext save:&error]) { // <-- App is crashing here

    }
}];
```

As far as I understand, there shouldn't be any concurrency issues with the `NSPersistentStore` behind the `backgroundContext` but that's what the crash is telling me.

In addition, this only occurs for less than 0.02% of my user base.  It's pretty rare (I'm unable to reproduce) but users are *not* able to recover from this without deleting and reinstalling the app.  It will consistently open and crash for them.

Note, this is only for 64-bit iOS 8.1.X - iOS 7.X and 8.0.X do not exhibit this behavior and I don't see it on anything older than an iPhone 5s.

---

Clarification: deleting the persistent store fixes this issue for all users.  This would seem to indicate it is not a concurrency issue.

---

Creation of Store & Contexts.

```
[_persistenStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                     configuration:nil
                                               URL:[DatabaseManager storeURL]
                                           options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
                                                     NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}
                                             error:&error];
```

Creating Contexts

```
_backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_backgroundContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
[_backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_persistenStoreCoordinator];
if ([_backgroundContext respondsToSelector:@selector(setName:)]) {
    [_backgroundContext setName:@"DatabaseManager.BackgroundQueue"];
}

_mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[_mainContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
[_mainContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:_persistenStoreCoordinator];
if ([_mainContext respondsToSelector:@selector(setName:)]) {
    [_mainContext setName:@"DatabaseManager.MainQueue"];
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(mainContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:_mainContext];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:)
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:_backgroundContext];
```

Listening for changes

```
- (void) mainContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [_backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        [self->_backgroundContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}

- (void) backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [_mainContext performBlock:^{
        NSArray* updated = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];

        // Fault all objects that will be updated.
        for (NSManagedObject* obj in updated) {
            NSManagedObject* mainThreadObject = [self->_mainContext objectWithID:obj.objectID];
            [mainThreadObject willAccessValueForKey:nil];
        }

        [self->_mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}
```

How code is executed on each of the contexts.  I pass a block into here:

```
- (void)executeBackgroundOperation:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *))operation {

    NSAssert(operation, @"No Background operation to perform");

    [_backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        operation(self->_backgroundContext);
    }];
}

- (void)executeMainThreadOperation:(void (^)(NSManagedObjectContext *))operation {
    NSAssert(operation, @"No Main Thread operation to perform");

    [_mainContext performBlock:^{
        operation(self->_mainContext);
    }];
}
```

---

The only other threads in the crash report that have a `lock` in them are two Javascript threads that look like this:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3a77cb38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a7fa2dd pthread_cond_wait + 38
2   libc++.1.dylib 0x39a11e91 _ZNSt3__118condition_variable4waitERNS_11unique_lockINS_5mutexEEE + 34
3   JavaScriptCore 0x2dcd4cb5 _ZN3JSC8GCThread16waitForNextPhaseEv + 102
4   JavaScriptCore 0x2dcd4d19 _ZN3JSC8GCThread12gcThreadMainEv + 50
5   JavaScriptCore 0x2db09597 _ZN3WTFL19wtfThreadEntryPointEPv + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a7f9e93 _pthread_body + 136
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a7f9e07 _pthread_start + 116
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a7f7b90 thread_start + 6
```

Comment: Hey Stephen, This crash will happen when multiple context pointing to single nsmanagedobject and modify relationship at same time and trying to save context. Make sure about modified table and its data at time to call save.

Comment: @Punita I only have one context saving to the persistent store, and all `save:` calls are made on a `performBlock:`, so unless the context is performing blocks in parallel, I don't see how this could happen.

Comment: As you written **updating/saving code is done on a performBlock** and **The crashes are all on the background context**. So what I understand is that you are inserting data in background context and than save managed object in performBlock of main thread. If I am correct then at time to execute save,  it will notify NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification of background's context and in this notification you will **info dictionary contains arrays with the managed objects that were inserted, deleted, and updated** 
as mentioned in Apple Document: Concurrency with Core Data

Comment: No, I am updating the objects on the background context in a performBlock.  In *the same block* I am saving the background context.  That is when the crash occurs.

Comment: Can you add code with creating of backgroundContext variable?

Comment: This is usually an indication that your concurrency is messed up.  Can you reproduce it?  Can you share the code?  I would search for any access on any MOC...  Core Data gets changes between releases... some that will cause breaks to code that previously worked when it had some sketchy synchronization.

Comment: @JodyHagins I cannot reproduce this.  It's a million-to-one kind of event.  Out of our 400,000+MAU only about 50 have experienced this issue.  It stops them completely from using the app.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov I added the code.  Keep in mind that this always happens for a small portion of our user base.  Deleting & reinstalling fixes the issue for all of them

Comment: At the time of the crash what is the stack trace for the other threads? Are any of them accessing the NSManagedObject or any other core data objects? I had a similar problem where other threads had mutex_locks but not the thread that was crashing.

Comment: @zimmryan no, the only other threads that have any kind of locks on them are Javascript ones.  (added above)

Comment: i believe this is an issue of heavy migration. Yes you should avoid a heavy migration on iOS. a) The heavy migration was not designed to run on iOS. It runs there more by accident than by design. Can you also print the content of "error" in [backgroundContext save:&error] usually Core Data errors contain internal errors that you can print out via accessing "error". b) Are you not missing the line _backgroundContext.parentContext = _mainContext;?

Comment: a) There is no `error` object - the app just crashes.  b) No, _backgroundContext is explicitly *not* a child of _mainContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in thinking this may not be a concurrency issue. Deleting and installing the app isually fixes core data errors when the migration hasn't been done properly.

If you released the app, changed the core data model, then released an update (without migration), this may be the source of your crash.

Follow this tutorial and see if it fixes your issue. http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Comment: this is the first version that we've not used a lightweight coredata migration.  We actually had to make a mapping model and a Migration Policy for one of the classes, but it's not the class which is updating when the app crashes.

Comment: But you may have messed the migration up. Either way, your problem is most likely due to a faulty migration. It's not a coincidence that this crash is happening after you did an update without the lightweight migration.

Comment: Maybe go back to that build and see if doing the migration fixes the problem. But I know it's hard to replicate. Maybe try to get an affected device the fixed version through testflight or something.  You could also try to load an earlier version on your device, update to the new version (without deleting old), and try to see if you can break the app.

Answer (score 0):

@StephenFurlani,

I am not expert of Core-data. But I like to solve issue. I think app getting crash while merge ManagedObject from backgroundContext to MainContext (as you mentioned your code):

```
- (void) backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [_mainContext performBlock:^{
        NSArray* updated = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];

        // Fault all objects that will be updated.
        for (NSManagedObject* obj in updated) {
            NSManagedObject* mainThreadObject = [self->_mainContext objectWithID:obj.objectID];
            [mainThreadObject willAccessValueForKey:nil];
        }

        [self->_mainContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }];
}
```

Here are some reference links:

- [Core Data from Scratch: Concurrency](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131) **Strategy 1: Notifications** you have already implemented. So try this solution with your scenario **Strategy 2: Parent/Child Managed Object Contexts**
- [iOS 8: Core Data and Batch Updates](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-core-data-and-batch-updates--cms-22164)

**Solution 1:** Try this below code:

```
NSMangedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
temporaryContext.parentContext = mainMOC;

[temporaryContext performBlock:^{
   // do something that takes some time asynchronously using the temp context

   // push to parent
   NSError *error;
   if (![temporaryContext save:&amp;error])
   {
      // handle error
   }

   // save parent to disk asynchronously
   [mainMOC performBlock:^{
      NSError *error;
      if (![mainMOC save:&amp;error])
      {
         // handle error
      }
   }];
}];
```

**Solution 2:** refresh value from backgroundContext's NSManagedObject to mainContext and then call processPendingChanges OR mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification of mainContext.
Try this code instead of above your code (backgroundContextDidSave method):

```
- (void) backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification*)notification
    {
        [_mainContext performBlock:^{
            NSArray* updated = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];

            // Fault all objects that will be updated.
            for (NSManagedObject* obj in updated) {
                NSManagedObject* mainThreadObject = [self->_mainContext objectWithID:obj.objectID];
                if (mainThreadObject) {
                    [self->_mainContext refreshObject: mainThreadObject mergeChanges:NO];
                }
            }

            [self->_mainContext processPendingChanges];
        }];
    }
```

**Very good help-full link:** [CORE DATA with multiple managed object contexts](http://www.slideshare.net/xzolian/core-data-with-multiple-managed-object-contexts)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar crash, not the same, but I was using a Stack #3 setup as well. The crash occurred on the same line as yours, during the save from background. What I found to be the cause was that when the CoreData operations spun up multiple threads, threads were finishing in the wrong order, but only sometimes. For us this was a problem as we had some dependent operations and object relationships in our model.

I fixed it by managing my own thread and my own queue for the background downloading. This way I could handle the order and always knew that I had a FIFO type flow. This also fixed the crash on the save.

I've added some code below if you wanted to give it a try.

```
- (void) keepAlive 
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];
}

- (void)backgroundThreadMain
{
    // Add selector to prevent CFRunLoopRunInMode from returning immediately
    [self performSelector:@selector(keepAlive) withObject:nil afterDelay:60];
    BOOL done = NO;

    do
    {
        // Start the run loop but return after each source is handled.
        SInt32    result = CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 10, YES);   

        // If a source explicitly stopped the run loop, or if there are no
        // sources or timers, go ahead and exit.
        if ((result == kCFRunLoopRunStopped) || (result == kCFRunLoopRunFinished))
        done = YES;
    }
    while (!done);
}

self.backgroundThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(backgroundThreadMain) object:nil];
[self.backgroundThread start];
```

Then anytime I needed to run a block of code I used a static reference to that thread.

```
[[CoreDataControl coreDataControlManager] performSelector:@selector(saveSite:) onThread:[CoreDataControl coreDataControlManager].backgroundThread withObject:site waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Worst case, you could wrap the save in a try catch block, and if an exception is thrown call reset on both your contexts. This will clear out any rowcache that may be causing the error.